# How to update Mono<Bar> based on a condition in Mono<Foo>?

Tags: project-reactor, reactive-streams

I have the below code from the answer given in this  [[stackoverflow question]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50778089/how-to-deal-with-two-fluxes-in-spring-reactive-programing)

```
bars = bars.flatMap(bar -> findByBarId(bar.getBarId())
                    .flatMap(foo -> {
                         bar.setIsInFoo(true);
                         return Mono.just(bar);
                    }).switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(bar)));
```

How to do above if I had single `Mono<Bar> bar Mono<Foo> foo` instead of Flux variant above and to get modified bar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exact same logic should apply whether you start from `Mono<Bar> bar` or `Flux<Bar> bars`. The code can be simplified a bit inside the first `flatMap` to use `map` and `defaultIfEmpty` to avoid the overhead of intermediate `Monos`:

```
Mono<Bar> source;
Mono<Bar> updated = source
    .flatMap(bar -> findByBarId(bar.getBarId())
        .map(foo -> {
            bar.setIsInFoo(true);
            return bar;
         })
        .defaultIfEmpty(bar)
    );
```